# ::selection issue with <ol> tag's <li> items in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, pseudo-element

I have added custom css for `::-moz-selection` and `::selection` like so below:

```
::-moz-selection {
  background: $the-color-i-like;
}
::selection {
  background: $the-color-i-like;
}
```

This looks great in all situations that [caniuse](http://caniuse.com) says it should (no `-webkit-` required in this context), except on `<ol>` tag's `<li>` items Safari (10.0.1). I can't seem to find any documentation to say that this is a known bug.

1. Has anyone come across this issue?
2. Does anyone have a way of resolving this, so that all content's `::selection` is consistent?

Answer (score -2):

There are different prefixes for various browsers. `-moz-` is for Fireforx only, whereas `-webkit-` covers Safari, Chrome, and the newer versions of Opera.

See more here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix

regarding your code, try

```
-webkit-::selection {
  background: $the-color-i-like;
}

-moz-::selection {
  background: $the-color-i-like;
}
::selection {
  background: $the-color-i-like;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Naltroc, I am aware of vendor proxies and the role they play. [Caniuse](http://caniuse.com) indicates that `-webkit-` is not required for `::selection` in Safari. It is working in Safari, except for this isolated instance; `<ol>` tag's `<li>` items.

Comment: I double checked this @Naltroc. Just to see if the vendor prefix might solve the problem. As I suspected, the browser ignored the `-webkit-` selector and the issue still remains.

Comment: In fairness, the ::-webkit-selection myth has been around for many years, and the reason that myth exists is the same reason for this answer: people assuming that just because a -moz- prefix exists for a certain feature, there must be a -webkit- prefix also.